# Firefox: visually flag redirect in address bar

Tags: firefox, redirect

I'm wondering if there's any way to have Firefox 3 (or IE 7 or safari 3.1 or Opera) flag that a redirect has occurred (i.e. any deltas between the hyperlink or URL entered into address bar, and the page you land on), whether you've arrived from a hyperlink or entering URL into address bar.

I've googled some, looked at the [linker addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8092), but the rightclick is an additional step I don't want to have to do.

Edit: If anybody can point me at the mozilla docs that show how to track clicked links and pages landed on in different tabs, i'll take a crack at writing a bookmarklet.  TIA

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this will help, since you don't want to do the right click for the linker add-on, but if I needed to do know if I was being redirected, I would use the [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) extension.  It supports regular expressions, so you can only get headers that include 'Location'.

The reason I don't think it is what you are looking for is that you have to open it before the link, it won't "flag" a redirect and pop a message up or anything.

Comment: Sorry, I should note that the extension is for Firefox.  I used it with version 2 and 3, but it may be available for older versions as well.  Also for Firefox, you can set the number of times a page can issue an HTTP redirect before giving up in about:config's Network.http.redirection-limit setting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's exactly what you need, but the **[NoRedirect](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11787)** extension seems to be related to your problem. Quoting it's description:

> NoRedirect lets the user take control of HTTP redirects. It can be used to interdict an ISP's DNS search redirection hijacks, preview/screen "shortened" URLs (e.g., TinyURL), stop the annoying redirection of "smart" error pages, etc.

If that's not what you wanted, looking into the extension's code might at least help you find some hooks for your proposed bookmarklet.